# Is these all these versions of Visual Studio needed?

Tags: visual-studio

I just started at a new company and on my computer I have:

- VS 2003
- VS 2005
- VS 2008
- VS 2010
- VS 2012
- VS 2013

We do have old apps we support but the plan is to upgrade them as we need to make changes to them.I should be able to open any app in VS 2013 correct? Whether its C# or VB

Do I need all these versions?

Comment: No one here is going to be able to answer that. It depends on the apps and what they use.

Comment: Need, probably not, but have to, certainly until apps are converted to newer compilers (IDE).

Comment: Keep in mind that the IDEs also support compiling using a previous version of the compiler toolchain. So while you probably do not need all of those IDEs, having the compiler versions installed can be *very* helpful when maintaining legacy applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no .NET 1.1 stuffs, you can remove VS 2003.

If no compact framework, VS 2008 is not needed.

VS 2013 does provide all the rest generally speaking.

Exceptions do exist, such as

- VS 2013 does not support many old frameworks such as MVC 1/2
- VS 2013 doesn't support old versions of Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is clearly No to the part of your question about opening any app in VS2013. Microsoft have removed support for some project types over the years, so you can not open "any app" in VS2013